# Kotlin Stream usage

Tags: kotlin

I have a code like below

```
items.forEach { item ->
            request += getDetails(item.propertyId, item.destinationIds)
            count++
            if( count == bulkSize) {
                save(request)
                request = ""
                count = 0
            }
        }

        if(!request.isEmpty()) {
            save(request)
        }
```

How can I use streaming api to make the code less verbose ?

Comment: Instead of streaming, I'd look at [`chunked()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/chunked.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
items.chunked(bulkSize) { chunk ->
    save(chunk.joinToString(separator = "") { item ->
        getDetails(item.propertyId, item.destinationIds) 
    })
}
```